# How to make a small rounded rectangle in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

The red rectangle center of my widget is too big and is not responsive to width and height arguments.

I have updated flutter, and android studio. I started with a container in the shape of a circle then, I used a flatbutton and gave it a shape. but when it becomes the rectangle it is the same size as the circle it resizes in. _isRecord is a boolean that is toggled when the button is pressed.

```
return Container(
  width: 80.0,
  height: 80.0,
  child: Container(
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: _press,
     ),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.red,
      shape: _isRecording ? BoxShape.rectangle : BoxShape.circle,
      borderRadius: _isRecording ? BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)) : null,
    ),
  ),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.black,
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    border: Border.all(width: 5.0, color: Colors.white),
  ),
);
```

It should look and function like the Voice Memos' record button. It should be a white circle stroke with a red center that when pressed becomes a smaller, rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use your Widget inside `Padding`

exam:

```
    InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isRecording = !_isRecording;
        });
      },
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(width: 5.0, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: Container(
            width: 40.0,
            height: 40.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                shape:
                    _isRecording ? BoxShape.rectangle : BoxShape.circle,
                borderRadius: _isRecording
                    ? BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))
                    : null,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear. This is what I am getting: https://imgur.com/8wa1KbU but I am trying to make the center square smaller than the stroke. Like this: https://imgur.com/PPEzRf8

Comment: It was perfect after just a few edits. All I needed to do was change the padding and size of the inner most container. Thanks for helping!