# How to create rounded rectangle box in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to create a box with a rectangular body. And my code is given below. Here **BoxShape** is underlined and the error message says: Enums can't be instantiated. Try using one of the defined constants. How will I solve this? I wanted to create a container box with rounded edges in flutter.

```
home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor:Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
      leading:Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            ),
    body: Scaffold(backgroundColor:Color(0xBBCCE3F0) ,
            body:   Center(
              child: Container(
                decoration:new BoxDecoration(
                  shape:BoxShape(BorderRadius.circular(10.0))
                ),
        color:Colors.white,
        child:SizedBox(height:500.0,width:300,
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Your question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244820/how-to-make-a-small-rounded-rectangle-in-flutter).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a small rounded rectangle in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244820/how-to-make-a-small-rounded-rectangle-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

Use this as decoration.This will give radius to container.

```
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

```
  > Container(
    >                 decoration:new BoxDecoration(
    >                   border: Border.all( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), ),
    >                 ),
    >         color:Colors.white,
    >         child:SizedBox(height:500.0,width:300,
    >         )
```